# Convert dataGridView to dataTable: error

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, datatable

I want to convert the DataGridView to DataTable.

```
using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
{
    dt.Columns.Add("column1", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("column2", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("column3", typeof(int));
    foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvR in dgQBM)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(dgvR.Cells[0].Value, dgvR.Cells[1].Value);
    }
}
```

The error:

```
foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 
'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' because 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' 
does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvR in dgQBM.Rows)
{
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with Rows

```
using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
            {
                dt.Columns.Add("column1", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("column2", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("column3", typeof(int));
                foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvR in dgQBM.Rows)
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add(dgvR.Cells[0].Value, dgvR.Cells[1].Value);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, in one line...speed performance code.

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)dgQBM.DataSource;
```

Comment: There is no indication that the grid is using a DataSource.